# Is there an alternative version to use std::panic::catch_unwind for mutable reference?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

To explain my question, i attach an example code not my real project to show the error.

```
fn divide(x: &mut i32, y: &mut i32) -> i32 {
    assert!(*y != 0, "Attempted to divide by zero");
    *x / *y
}

#[test]
fn test_divide() {
    let mut x = 10;
    let mut y = 2;
    assert_eq!(divide(&mut x, &mut y), 5);
    let mut x = 10;
    let mut y = -2;
    assert_eq!(divide(&mut x, &mut y), -5);

    let result = std::panic::catch_unwind(|| divide(&mut x, &mut 0));
    assert!(result.is_err());
    let err = result.unwrap_err();
    let msg = err.downcast_ref::<&'static str>().unwrap();
    let mssss = "Attempted to divide by zero";
    assert_eq!(msg, &mssss);
}
```

in last example, because x and 0 are mutable references in the test_divide, so i won't be able to use this catch_unwind.

Is there another way to catch this error?  Thank you

I tried to change the mutable reference in my project so i can use this catch_unwind, but it broke many other codes

Comment: In your code it doesn't look like you need mutable references (or references at all).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`move`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.move.html) semantics for the closure you pass to `catch_unwind` or use [`#[should_panic]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-01-writing-tests.html#checking-for-panics-with-should_panic):

```rust
pub fn divide(x: &mut i32, y: &mut i32) -> i32 {
    assert!(*y != 0, "Attempted to divide by zero");
    *x / *y
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::divide;

    #[test]
    fn test_divide() {
        let mut x = 10;
        let mut y = 2;
        assert_eq!(divide(&mut x, &mut y), 5);
        let mut x = 10;
        let mut y = -2;
        assert_eq!(divide(&mut x, &mut y), -5);

        let result = std::panic::catch_unwind(move || divide(&mut x, &mut 0));
        assert!(result.is_err());
        let err = result.unwrap_err();
        let msg = err.downcast_ref::<&'static str>().unwrap();
        let mssss = "Attempted to divide by zero";
        assert_eq!(msg, &mssss);
    }
    
    #[test]
    #[should_panic(expected = "Attempted to divide by zero")]
    fn test_divide2() {
        let mut x = 10;
        divide(&mut x, &mut 0);
    }   
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d412adaac1ed16b53aa326b17ae1b0df)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with mutable references is that they are not [`UnwindSafe`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/panic/trait.UnwindSafe.html). This is because data could have invariants, that are broken temporarily in the middle of the function and then resumed. If we panic when they are broken, then everything is fine - unless we catch the panic later, in this case we can observe the broken invariant.

If you are sure you don't have any invariants that can be violated, you can wrap your closure in [`AssertUnwindSafe`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/panic/struct.AssertUnwindSafe.html):

```rust
#[test]
fn test_divide() {
    let mut x = 10;
    let mut y = 2;
    assert_eq!(divide(&mut x, &mut y), 5);
    let mut x = 10;
    let mut y = -2;
    assert_eq!(divide(&mut x, &mut y), -5);

    let result = std::panic::catch_unwind(std::panic::AssertUnwindSafe(|| divide(&mut x, &mut 0)));
    assert!(result.is_err());
    let err = result.unwrap_err();
    let msg = err.downcast_ref::<&'static str>().unwrap();
    let mssss = "Attempted to divide by zero";
    assert_eq!(msg, &mssss);
}
```